# Formatting javascript array list into specific format using lodah\handlebar template or any other JS library

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, handlebars.js, lodash

I have a JavaScript array which looks like this

```
var arr = ["[Dim1].[Mem1].&1","[Dim2].[Mem1].&2","[Dim1].[Mem1].&5","[Dim2].[Mem1].&77","[Dim3].[Mem1].&1"]
```

**What I want: I want  a string in this format**

```
{
    [Dim1].[Mem1].&1, [Dim1].[Mem1].&5
},
{
     [Dim2].[Mem1].&2, [Dim2].[Mem1].&77
},
{
     [Dim3].[Mem1].&1"]
}
```

I am able to do this by:

1. Loop over all the items in array & then split them with .&
2. Create another list based on [dim].[mem] combination. In our case the list will have [Dim3].[Mem1], [Dim1].[Mem1], [Dim2].[Mem1].
3. Now have two loop - One for every item in unique list and one for every item in original list & check if the item is original list contains the current item in unique list & then form the string.

Is there anyway to achieve this with the help of a template or handlebar template or any other JavaScript library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.groupBy`](http://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) and Regular Expressions, to group the elements

```
var regExp = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
console.log(_.groupBy(arr, function(currentItem) {
    var match, result = "";
    while ((match = regExp.exec(currentItem)) !== null) {
        result += match[1];
    }
    return result;
}));
```

**Output**

```
{ Dim1Mem1: [ '[Dim1].[Mem1].&1', '[Dim1].[Mem1].&5' ],
  Dim2Mem1: [ '[Dim2].[Mem1].&2', '[Dim2].[Mem1].&77' ],
  Dim3Mem1: [ '[Dim3].[Mem1].&1' ] }
```

Comment: If I am not wrong the solution you gave only identify the unique items but how can I convert the data into format I am looking for? Can you also explain how you are splitting the array (in other words on what basis you are creating the group).

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite The code is **NOT** getting unique values. The grouping is done based on the strings within opening and ending square brackets.

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite Did you expand the object in the console? Just click the small triangle next to Object in the console window.

Comment: Yes I did. The solution is working. But can you please explain it to me how its working? Also is there any way to add the "{" (as shown in my question) at the start and end of each group or I have to loop again ?

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite Can you please make sure that you are getting the output like [this](http://oi59.tinypic.com/29fqpzm.jpg), with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8sv3/) first?

Comment: I am getting the output like that. Please explain me how this is done

Comment: So are you saying the grouping is done based on first [ bracket and last ] bracket ? Can you please explain me the reg exp

Comment: The RegExp, captures whatever between the First open bracket and the first closing bracket and on the next iteration of the while loop, it does the same but from the last closing bracket.